# Html Links when clicked fail to execute

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario when if someone clicks on any link in the navigation menu bar of my homepage then nothing executes. The page does present the hover effect and the cursour changes but nothing happens when a menu item is clicked.

Homepage where this issue can be seen
http://www.dreamjobrecruitment.com

How ever within my site on the inner pages this navigation bar does work. For example
http://www.dreamjobrecruitment.com/testimonials.html

I have inspected and cross referenced the code with firebug but have failed to spot any difference as yet in the code between the homepage and inner pages.

If I had to guess I would guess this has something to do with a z index property although I can not see one set and at the same time the cursour on the mouse changes and the text colour presents the hover effect.

I am quite unsure of how to proceed with this. Any feedback would be welcome. This has happened in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox Browsers. I've not tested it in any additional browsers.

Comment: Really strange. I also can't see anything preventing the click.

Comment: Is there perhaps something in the JS preventing default? The links on the testimonial page seem to have a class of `external` which does not seem to have any styling. The links on the home page do not have this class applied.

Comment: in js  i saw "target":"" . I don't know is this the cause.

Comment: On a side note, try not to use deprecated code. Eg. "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Comment: On another sidenote, try to make your question self consistent and not relying on external stuff that might change - once you've fixed this on your site this question becomes useless to others stopping by, because they cannot reproduce. Try to produce as simple code snippet as possible that demonstrates your issue in your question.

Comment: yea, as pointed out by @Paulie_D this is pretty sure an `js` issue somewhere in your code, if you switch off `js` completely the links do respond, also if you give for example the `testimonials`'s `<a>` also the class `external` the links respond